# How to avoid the blocking effect of a large job in SLURM once it starts?

Tags: slurm, hpc

Occasionally someone submits an important job to Slurm which takes a long time and uses a lot of resources. Once it starts, it blocks all other tasks for a long time. If an administrator doesn't want to interrupt it, but would like to push some other small job in the meantime, what are the options?

I tried suspending the job, but it doesn't release the resources (all 128 CPU):

```
ognjen@schopenhauer:/data/og/GGSpi$ squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
             56299     short cromwell     root PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
             56298     short cromwell     root PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
             56297     short REDItool    kosar  S 1-03:47:59      1 schopenhauer
```

I tried updating the priorities of the other jobs, updating parameters of the running job etc. I could be doing it wrong.
Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

Comment: I thank you for the decorum lesson. Considering I can suspend someone's job, and you can see the tasks waiting as root, you can guess that I am an administrator for this issue. I might be a bad one, but politely waiting is not a part of my tasks.

Comment: Fair enough :) Can I have some Prosecco and mortadella now, please?

Comment: I'm still unloading my trolley!

Comment: did you get an answer eventually?

Comment: Sadly, no. Still waiting.